# Allocating temporary VMs to parallelize one-shot batch jobs (GCP, Azure or AWS)

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I am evaluating options for launching arbitrary Python tasks/scripts on temporary cloud VMs that get shut down once the job is complete. I am looking across all cloud providers, but the ideal solution should not be vendor-specific. Here is what I found:

- Docker Swarm / Kubernetes / Nomad for spinning up docker containers. All look attractive, but cannot confirm if they can terminate VMs once the task is complete.
- Cloud Functions/Lambdas look great, but works only for short-lived (few minutes) tasks. Also, GCP supports only JavaScript.
- Spins up/down VMs explicitly from a launch script with vendor specific commands. Straightforward and should work.
- AWS Batch, Azure Batch - vendor-specific services for batch jobs
- AWS Data Pipeline, Azure Data Factory, Google Dataflow - vendor-specific services for data pipelines

Did I miss any good option? Does any container orchestration service like Docker Swarm support allocation and deallocation of multiple temporary VMs to run a one-shot job?

Comment: So from my understanding your objective would be to have a system that could execute on any cloud some Python while keeping the resource open only when needed. 

Have you looked at any open job schedulers? By chaining operations you would create your third scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My objective is to find the easiest way to run a custom batch job like a crawler w/o managing VMs at all and paying only for compute hours I actually used. So far it looks like CCP Dataflow is the best match - it can run tasks in parallel, it is based on an open-source API (Apache Beam) and can manage VM. I confirmed that people use it for ad-hoc jobs. And yes I looked at some open-source job schedulers like Celery and AirFlow - they don't manage VMs for you :( Don't understand why this question gets downvoted ... How can I improve it? I think it is a legit problem.

Comment: I think the keyword to look for should be "multi-cloud job scheduler". From the [google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=job%20scheduler%20multi-cloud), I know ActiveEon provide this feature through the [iaas connector](https://github.com/ow2-proactive/connector-iaas) but Jams may have similar properties.